# Remove object from array with multiple classes in Java

Tags: java, arrays, object, inheritance, polymorphism

I'm fairly new in Java, and I having some difficulties on this exercise. I have to create a "Piggy Bank" where the user can deposit coins with different values and currency (Euro, Dolar, Real etc), as well as remove them afterwards and convert the total value to the desired currency. It's proposed that we create a abstract superclass for Coin, and three subclasses for Euro, Dolar and Real.
I could get pretty far without a hussle, but I can't figure out how to remove, for example, any 10 dollar coin in the bank, and leave others 10 dollars or 10 euros coins untouched, like a Iterator that scans the array and when he meet the criteria (Dollar, value 10), he removes that object and stop running.
I'm creating an array list and putting coins on it through this blocks of code:

```
ArrayList<Coin> list = new ArrayList<Coin>();

double euroCoinValue = scan.nextDouble();
list.add(new Euro(euroCoinValue)); 

double dollarCoinValue = scan.nextDouble();
list.add(new Dollar(dollarCoinValue));
```

Comment: Your question is either incomplete or nonsensical. Of course you cannot distinguish between two particular `Coin` objects of they have the same currency and same amounts, assuming you have no identifier as a member field defined in your class. Are you trying to represent coins belongoing to a certain person or account?

Comment: By the way, never use a floating-point type for money. Use `BigDecimal` class.

Comment: I was, indeed, unclear. I'm not trying to remove a SPECIFIC 10 dollar coin, but ANY of the 10 dollar coins that exists in the Array, but only one of those coins. Like a iterator that scans the array and when he meet the criteria (Dollar, value 10), he removes that object and stop running.

Comment: Can you share the program and the error you are experiencing? Looking at the code (or possibly running it locally will help answer this quicker)

Comment: Edit the body of your Question with those clarifications.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my understanding of what you wanted to do. Let me know if I missed your actual question.

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main main = new Main();
    main.testRemoveOneOfTheDollars();

    main.testRemoveOneReal();

    main.testRemoveTwoReal();

  }

  private PiggyBank setup() {
    PiggyBank piggyBank = new PiggyBank();
    piggyBank.add(new Euro(BigDecimal.valueOf(10L)));
    piggyBank.add(new Dollar(BigDecimal.valueOf(10L)));
    piggyBank.add(new Euro(BigDecimal.valueOf(10L)));
    piggyBank.add(new Dollar(BigDecimal.valueOf(10L)));
    piggyBank.add(new Real(BigDecimal.valueOf(10L)));
    return piggyBank;

  }

  public void testRemoveOneOfTheDollars() {
    PiggyBank piggyBank = setup();
    piggyBank.printCurrentState();
    piggyBank.remove("Main$Dollar");

  }

  public void testRemoveOneReal() {
    PiggyBank piggyBank = setup();
    piggyBank.printCurrentState();
    piggyBank.remove("Main$Real");
    piggyBank.printCurrentState();
  }

  public void testRemoveTwoReal() {
    PiggyBank piggyBank = setup();
    piggyBank.printCurrentState();
    piggyBank.remove("Main$Real");
    piggyBank.printCurrentState();
    try {
      piggyBank.remove("Main$Real");
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
      System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    piggyBank.printCurrentState();
  }

  class PiggyBank {
    private List<Coin> coins;

    public PiggyBank() {
      coins = new ArrayList<Coin>();
    }

    public void add(Coin newCoin) {
      System.out.println("Adding coin [" + newCoin + "]");
      coins.add(newCoin);
    }

    public Coin remove(String coinType) {
      System.out.println("Removing coin of type [" + coinType + "]");
      int numOfCoins = coins.size();
      for (int i = 0; i < numOfCoins; i++) {
        Coin toReturn = coins.get(i);
        if (toReturn.getClass().getName().equalsIgnoreCase(coinType)) {
          coins.remove(i);
          System.out.println("Removed coin [" + toReturn + "]");
          return toReturn;
        }
      }
      throw new IllegalStateException("No Coins of type [" + coinType + "] exist in PiggyBank");
    }

    public void printCurrentState() {
      List<String> coinStrs = coins.stream().map(Coin::toString).collect(Collectors.toList());
      System.out.println("PiggyBank Current State [" + coinStrs + "]");

    }

  }

  abstract class Coin {
    protected BigDecimal value;

    public Coin(BigDecimal value) {
      this.value = value;
    }

    public BigDecimal getValue() {
      return value;
    }

    public String toString() {
      return "value: [" + getValue() + "], type [" + this.getClass().getName() + "]\n";
    }

  }

  class Euro extends Coin {
    public Euro(BigDecimal value) {
      super(value);
    }
  }

  class Dollar extends Coin {
    public Dollar(BigDecimal value) {
      super(value);
    }
  }

  class Real extends Coin {
    public Real(BigDecimal value) {
      super(value);
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Good answer. But why not use `Class` class objects rather than textual class name?

Comment: @BasilBourque - I had started using that and ran out of time while typing this up and ended up patching it with String based solution. I agree the recommended solution is to use Class instead of String. I knew someone would catch it :P